# How to set kafka committedOffset in flink?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I already set committed offsetd by:

```
properties.setProperty("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
properties.setProperty("auto.commit.enable", "true");
properties.setProperty("enable.auto.commit", "true");

FlinkKafkaConsumer08<MobilePageEvent> kafkaConsumer =
            new FlinkKafkaConsumer08<>(
                    "mobile-event.page-resource", SCHEMA, properties);
```

But in the web UI, I get invalid committed offsets:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After enabling check pointing, it works now:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment environment =
            StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

environment.enableCheckpointing(5000);
```